# What's the name of this layout style?

Tags: html, layout

There is a layout style that has been widely used the last couple of years or so, the one with a full-width image near the top, a discreet menu above the image, and some form of content below the image.

Is this layout style called something?

A few examples:

https://www.airbnb.com

https://www.wannafind.dk

https://www.code42.com/crashplan

https://www.wannafind.dk

http://www.e-boks.dk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the name of the layout, but it's a very common theme for Bootstrappers: http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/ You have themes like: Creative, Clean Blog, Agency, Freelancer, GrayScale, Landing page +++

I guess the amount of existing themes with that exact layout can be the reason why "everyone" uses it!

Also there's a lot of different templates that is built the same way.